# Crear una lista <select> desde una clase en C#

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, mvc, html-select

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con modelo MVC donde desde el controlador mando generar/cargar un formulario para capturar una información.

El código funciona perfectamente al momento de generar los campos de captura de texto (tags ***input***)

```
html += "<div class='col s6'>";
html += "<div class='editor-field'>";
html += "<div class='input-field col s12'>";
html += "<input type = 'text' id='txtFrecuencia' name='txtFrecuencia'/>";
html += "<label> Frecuencia:</label>";
html += "</div>";
html += "</div>";
html += "</div>";
```

Pero al momento de generar la lista desplegable, esta unicamente me despliega la etiqueta que le asigno, peor nunca despliega la lista (tag ***select***)

```
html += "<div class='col s6'>";
html += "<div class='editor-field'>";
html += "<div class='input-field col s12'>";
html += "<select id = 'ddlIncluidoPpto' name='ddlIncluidoPpto'>";
html += "<option value='1'>SI</option>";
html += "<option value='0'>NO</option>";
html += "</select>";
html += "<label>¿Se incluye en el presupuesto?</label>";
html += "</div>";
html += "</div>";
html += "</div>";
```

esto es lo que me genera una vez que corro el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al inicio de la pagina tengo otras listas desplegables que esas se llenan de manera dinámica según unos queries a SQL, pero esos funcionan sin problemas, me imagino que porque están codificados dentro de la vista en lugar de generarse dentro de una función del controlador

Adjunto el codigo de las desplegables que si funcionan

```
<div class="col s6">
<div class="editor-field">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<select id="ddlccosto" name="ddlccosto" data-loading-text="data" data-url="/api/EgresosCentroCosto/ListaHonorarios" onchange="CargarFormulario(false);" data-method="GET"></select>
<label>Rubro</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col s6">
<div class="editor-field">
<div class="input-field col s12">
<select id="ddlrubro6" name="ddlrubro6" data-loading-text="data" data-url="/api/EgresosCentroCosto/ListaDeudores" onchange="CargarFormulario(false);" data-method="GET"></select>
<label>Deudor</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

¿Podrían darme una pista de que es lo que esta fallando para que no se generen las listas desplegables que mando desde la función del controlador?

Answer (score 0):

veras probé tu código y no conseguí error alguno

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body id=generate>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html = "";
    html += "<div class='col s6'>";
    html += "<div class='editor-field'>";
    html += "<div class='input-field col s12'>";
    html += "<input type = 'text' id='txtFrecuencia' name='txtFrecuencia'/>";
    html += "<label> Frecuencia:</label>";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";

    html += "<div class='col s6'>";
    html += "<div class='editor-field'>";
    html += "<div class='input-field col s12'>";
    html += "<select id = 'ddlIncluidoPpto' name='ddlIncluidoPpto'>";
    html += "<option value='1'>SI</option>";
    html += "<option value='0'>NO</option>";
    html += "</select>";
    html += "<label>¿Se incluye en el presupuesto?</label>";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";
    html += "</div>";

    document.getElementById("generate").innerHTML = html;
    console.log(html);
</script>
</html>

puede ser que te este dando problema el css y te este generando conflicto con la ejecución, puedes probar con un setTimeout a ver si con un retraso en la carga te agarra.
También puedes borrar cache del nav.

Espero haberte ayudado
```

Comment: El tema es que estoy generando el html desde una clase de c# no desde el javascript de la misma página, y el tema es que el html se genera correctamente (ya lo corrobore poniendolo en un archivo html externo al proyecto), pero al momento de mostrarlo desde el proyecto, simplemente no lo hace, a diferencia de los demás controles.